# Where can I build a Thermal Power generator in XCom

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

According to the description, Thermal generators must be built "over steam vents".  Naturally, I assumed that this meant the space above the one marked "steam", so I cleared out rubble and tried to build on that space, only to find that I could not.

Do I need to actually build on the space that says "Steam", or above it as the description says?  If above it, is there any reason I can't build on a space I've cleared out? (other than money, which was not an issue).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only build thermal generators *on* squares in your base view that have "Steam" in them.  This is a bit confusing in the tooltip, but that's the way it's implemented.

There's no reason to avoid building on an adjacent square - there's nothing unusual about the space above a "Steam" square.  However, there is an adjacency bonus for power plants.  Therefore, you might want to consider building another power plant type there, in order to get the bonus power.